# artisan key save to variable

Tags: bash, laravel, laravel-artisan

from some reason I am unable to save output of artisan command into variable as a string.
What am I doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/sh
key=$(php artisan key:generate --show)
echo $key
```

Says `stdout is not a tty`

Thank you

Comment: Are you using Windows? On linux it works.

Comment: GitBash under Windows

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure, you are running this script with same folder `artisan` command ?

You should run this script with same folder with `artisan`

or you should fix script like this,

```
#!/bin/sh
key=$(php /projectpath/artisan key:generate --show)
echo $key
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Artisan key is being generated, but not saved. Here is the code https://gitlab.com/snippets/1723831